# Hive external table creation stored as sequence file with location

Tags: hive, hiveql

```
create external table sequence_snappy_extn(order_id int,order_date bigint,order_customer_id int,order_status string)
row format delimited
fields terminated by '\t'
stored as sequencefile 
location '/user/cloudera/problem10/sequence_snappy'
```

hive> select order_id from sequence_snappy_extn limit 5;
OK
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: WritableName can't load class: orders
Time taken: 0.949 seconds

Comment: and what is the issue?

Comment: And are there files in the location `/user/cloudera/problem10/sequence_snappy` ?

Comment: Files are present in desired location - /user/cloudera/problem10/sequence_snappy Found 5 items
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera          0 2018-05-04 22:57 /user/cloudera/problem10/sequence_snappy/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera     289884 2018-05-04 22:57 /user/cloudera/problem10/sequence_snappy/part-m-00000
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera     289692 2018-05-04 22:57 /user/cloudera/problem10/sequence_snappy/part-m-00001
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera     289970 2018-05-04 22:57 /user/cloudera/problem10/sequence_snappy/part-m-00002

Comment: How was was the data in /user/cloudera/problem10/sequence_snappy written to?

Comment: Data was imported to below path using below command 
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db --username root --password cloudera --table orders --as-sequencefile --target-dir /user/cloudera/problem10/sequence_snappy --compress --compression-codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec --delete-target-dir

Comment: Sqoop would have created a file orders.java in the directory from where you ran the sqoop import command. It represents one row of the orders table. It can serialize and deserialize data to and from the SequenceFile format. You can use it for writing a Hive SerDe that can read from this table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a conversion problem
use `--verbose` flag in sqoop and see how many "snappy" jars are being imported

usually, these are the libraries might import the jar

- $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/
- $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/
- $SQOOP_HOME/lib/

if there are multiple jar files imported from multiple libs, make sure your sqoop command is using only one